# How to filter/regex with Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a textfile contains lines with below:

```
Nmap scan report for 48.168.151.137
Host is up (0.057s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap scan report for 133.41.164.3
Host is up (0.056s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap scan report for 111.40.49.24
Host is up (0.056s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

I want to use notepad++ regex to remove all texts and just leave the IPS with port.

For example below:

```
48.168.151.137:80
133.41.164.3:80
111.40.49.24:80
```

I've tried my best with failed attempts. Kindly can anybody help me out.

Thank you in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: use a programming language to extract what you want.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Can't do it with regex?

Comment: @mzabox: You can, why not? Use `.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})[\s\S]*?\n(\d+)/tcp\h+open\h+http\R*` -> `$1:$2\n`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works perfectly, Thanks a million buddy, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit flys to Mr. Wiktor Stribizew, answer is:

```
Find: .*?(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})[\s\S]*?\n(\d+)/tcp\h+open\h+http\R*
Replace with: $1:$2\n
```

Answer (score 1):

I learnt something from viktor's answer
and prepared my second answer, completely working as intended,  try it,
Find what: `.+?(\d.+)[\s\S]+?(\d+)/.+[\n]`
Replace with: `$1:$2`
Below is photo for explanation of regex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this regex,  it will bring the same result as desired then try this  ....

Find: `for\s(\d.*)|(\d+)/|.*?`

Replace: `$1$2`

But there will be spaces in between results ,

`48.168.151.137`

`80`

`133.41.164.3`

`80`

`111.40.49.24`

`80`
The below picture is used for explanation...
[image]

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: I'm using (nmm text editor ) by maok, from playstore on my android Mobile, ,  I just checked your both example including mine one too,, all gave the same result... thanks toto

Comment: Corrected comment: Note that `^.*for\s(\d.*)|.*$` is interpreted as `(?:^.*for\s(\d.*))|(?:.*$)` in Notepad++. Perhaps you meant `^(?:.*for\s(\d.*)|.*)$`.

Comment: I corrected my answer with a short regex, ,, and also added a photo for explanation...